# My program ignores a for cycle in a omp parallel region

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I have to do a program that calculates Pi by Monte Carlo technique. So I am using omp library to create the threads, no error is shown and it actually works if I set the number of threads to just 1 thread. But if I try with 2 threads or more, the cycle is completely ignored.
Any idea why?

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(threads) private(nthreads,points_inside) //parallel region
    {
        int tid_set_clock = omp_get_thread_num() + 1;
        srand(time(0)*tid_set_clock);
        double coord[2];//coordinates
        double dist_cent;//distance from center of a unitary circle to any point
        nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        for(int i=0;i<(num_points*(1/nthreads));i++){//generaion of N points
            coord[0] = 2*((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX));
            coord[1] = 2*((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX));
            dist_cent = sqrt(pow((1-coord[0]),2)+pow((1-coord[1]),2));
            if(dist_cent>=1){
                points_inside--;
            }
        }
    }
```

That's the parallel section, if the number of threads is 1, it will work just fine but if it's 2 or more then it just doesn't enter the **for** cycle

Any idea of what's happening?

Comment: Why are you calling `srand()` in the parallel block? And `rand()` isn't thread safe anyways so shouldn't be used. (And notobdy every remembers that `hypot()` is a function...)

Comment: Your for loop never runs because 1/2, 1/3, etc. is 0.

Comment: Additionally, please use `#pragma omp for` rather than a manual work splitting of the threads: it is easier to read and reduces the introduction of possible mistakes/bugs.

Comment: Is 'nthreads' an integer? if so, the expression (1/nthreads) evaluates to zero. therefore the number of iterations in the loop are 0.

Comment: Thank you all, I fixed  everyhing and it works great